# Pasar un struct a un metodo de una clase

Tags: c++, clase, punteros, struct

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que uso un struct para guardar información dada por el usuario:

```
struct Cancion{
    string nombre;
    string autor;
    string interprete;
    int ranking;
};

struct Cancion llenarInfo(struct Cancion song){
    cout<<"Dame el nombre de la cancion: \n"<<endl;
    getline(cin,song.nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Dame el nombre del autor: \n"<<endl;
    getline(cin,song.autor);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Dame el nombre del interprete: \n"<<endl;
    getline(cin,song.interprete);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Dame el ranking de la cancion: \n"<<endl;
    cin>>song.ranking;
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

y tengo una clase con los metodos "inserta, imprime y elimina" que son para llenar una lista que contenga los datos mencionados anteriormente

```
void Lista::inserta(int pos, struct elem){
    if(llena()){
        cout<<"Lista llena\n";
    }else if(pos!=-1 and !posValida(pos)){
        cout<<"Posicion invalida\n";
    }else{
        int i=last;
        while(i>pos){
            lista[i+1]=lista[i];
            i--;
        }
        //insercion despues del punto de interes
        lista[pos+1]=elem;
        last++;
    }
}
```

```
void Lista::elimina(int pos){
    if(!posValida(pos)){
        cout<<"Posicion invalida\n";
    }else{
        int i=pos;
        while(i<last){
            lista[i]=lista[i+1];
            i++;
        }
    last--;
    }
}
```

```
void Lista::imprime(){
    int i=0;
    while(i<=last){
        cout<<lista[i]<<", ";
        i++;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

En el main use:

```
song[i]=llenarInfo(song[i]);
mylista.inserta(last,song[i]);
```

pero me marca errores en la definición del método en la clase diciendo que se esperaba un identificador antes del ')':

```
void inserta(int, struct);
```

y que el prototipo no encuentra alguna en la clase, esto en la implementación y en el main.

Cual sería la manera correcta de definir y llamar al método o si hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Asumo que no quieres poner `void Lista::inserta(int pos, struct Cancion elem)`, sino que quieres que esta función sea válida para cualquier struct de entrada?

Comment: @Trauma, Quiero hacer una lista y que en cada posición tenga un struct, no que cada posicion sea un elemento de éste (nombre, autor, etc)

Comment: @MrJavy, en éste caso, el struct de entrada sólo sería "Canción", lo intenté `void Lista::inserta(int pos, struct Cancion elem)`, pero queda igual

Comment: @Trauma te refieres a que tengo que ponerle `struct elem` en la declaración?, que no solo es el tipo de dato a usar? y como dijiste, que en c++ no se tiene que poner `struct para indicar que el tipo es eso.` que se supone que le ponga?

Comment: ok ok, entendido, gracias, y asi fue como apredí a ponerlo y en uno que otro lugar leí

Answer (score 0):

Tu función `struct Cancion llenarInfo(struct Cancion song)` anuncia que retorna un `struct Cancion`, sin embargo, no existe línea de return en dicha función, por lo que retorna `Undefined` (*[fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32513844/14325407)*).

Así pues tu main:

```
song[i]=llenarInfo(song[i]);
mylista.inserta(last,song[i]);
```

Sería equivalente a:

```
song[i]=Undefined;
mylista.inserta(last,Undefined);
```

Y como entenderás, produce error.

Además, tu función `void Lista::inserta(int pos, struct elem)` emplea `struct elem`, parámetro incompleto que debería ser: `struct Cancion elem`

**Corrigiendo** estos dos errores deberías avanzar en la resolución del problema.

*Funciones*

```
void llenarInfo(struct Cancion song)
void Lista::inserta(int pos, struct Cancion elem)
```

*Main*

```
llenarInfo(song[i]);
mylista.inserta(last,song[i]);
```

Espero que sea útil ;)

Comment: ¿ Por favor, podrías indicarme en que sitio del lenguaje se define las características del valor o palabra reservada `Undefined` ?

Comment: El caso es que `Undefined` no es un valor o palabra en sí, es un comportamiento. Digamos que haces la división `475/0`, ¿cual es el resultado? Tanto podría ser 1 como infinito o 0. El concepto de **comportamiento indefinido** o `Undefined` se aplica por los casos en que el programador no ha sido riguroso y permite que el código pueda tomar "decisiones" por sí mismo. En este caso debe tenerse en cuenta el funcionamiento del PC, pues el resultado será habitualmente el contenido del registro `%eax` y este contenido dependerá de cómo el compilador emplee este registro durante las operaciones.

Comment: Pues me has liado todavía más, porque en el primer párrafo de tu respuesta dices `retorna Undefined`. ¿ Como se puede retornar un comportamiento ?

Comment: La división `475/0` no es indefinida, ni puede ser un valor indeterminado, está muy definida. El comportamiento indefinido se da cuando el estándar del lenguaje no define cuál es el comportamiento esperable en una situación.

Comment: Cuando digo que retorna `Undefined` no me refiero a que retorne un comportamiento, me refiero a que ni tu ni yo podemos tener ni idea del valor que retornará la función.

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar cualquier dato (ya sea un tipo básico o un objeto) a cualquier tipo de función (una función libre, una función miembro o una lambda) tendrás en C++ **siempre las mismas opciones**:

### Paso por copia.

```
void funcion(tipo copia) { ... }
```

En este caso, el dato `copia` entra en la función `funcion` como una copia del dato original, esto implica que cualquier cambio realizado en la copia quedará dentro de la función.

### Paso por referencia.

```
void funcion(tipo &referencia) { ... }
//                ^ <---- Referencia
```

En este caso, el dato `referencia` entra en la función `funcion` como una referencia al dato original, esto implica que cualquier cambio realizado en la referencia se reflejará fuera de la función que la recibe.

---

Dicho esto, voy a señalar el error que te ha motivado a crear la pregunta:

> [...] me marca errores en la definición del método en la clase diciendo que se esperaba un identificador antes del ')':
>
> ```
> void inserta(int, struct);
> ```

La palabra clave `struct` se usa para declarar objetos de tipo `struct`; cuando la escribes el compilador espera que añadas después un nombre (identificador), seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
void inserta(int, struct nombre_de_la_estructura);
```

Ten en cuenta que en C++ las estructuras son tipos de primer orden, así que no necesitas la palabra clave `struct` para usar su tipo, ten también en cuenta que estás pasando la estructura **por copia**, así que todos los datos que le asignes se perderán al salir de la función.